# What is elliptic curve cryptography and why is it important to Monero?

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve, curve25519

What is elliptic curve cryptography and why is it important to Monero?

Please provide both a basic description and an in depth description of the type found on [Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elliptic curve cryptography (ECC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) is a form of [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) where mathematical properties of elliptic curves are used to ensure security of cryptographic methods used. This allows to perform the following in a secure way:

- Public key encryption, where the sender can encrypt a message using the recipient's public key, and the recipient can decrypt it using his private key.
- Signature, where the signer can sign a message using his private key, and anyone can verify the signature using the signer's public key.
- Shared secret key, where any 2 parties can securely agree upon a shared secret key, which is then normally used as the key for symetric encryption to encrypt any further messages between the 2 parties.

It is important to Monero, because it facilitates important operations such as key-pair creation (used for generating Monero addresses), Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (used in the Monero stealth-address scheme), and signing and verifying transactions. The curve used by Monero is one of the [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/), and is the Curve25519, widely used for [many other](https://ianix.com/pub/curve25519-deployment.html) secure applications.

For further reading on ECC, [here's](http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/) my go-to link.